# C# - WCF Message Inspector Doesn't Run

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics

I'm working on refactoring a project that has about 5 different web services, and each web service had a ton of identical code, including adding a message inspector onto the client endpoint behaviors so we could see the request and response data.

Part of the refactoring was to come up with a cleaner model for the web services (e.g. one abstract base service model that did all the common setup, including the addition of the message inspector).

Now, when I make the service calls (invoked via reflection), the service call works perfectly fine, and if I add a breakpoint right after the response comes back, I can see that there are 3 behaviors added to the client's endpoint:

```
[0] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior
[1] System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials
[2] MyProject.MyMessageInspector
```

...but the message inspector code doesn't seem to get called at all anymore. The inspector code is currently identical to the MSDN example here (except for the class name):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.110).aspx

The primary difference is that I'm now using generic methods for setting up the client, which looks like this:

```
...sanity checks, etc...
TClient client = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClient), binding, new EndpointAddress(url)) as TClient;
ClientBase<TInterface> _clientBase = client as ClientBase<TInterface>;
...credentials, timeout, etc...
MyEndpointBehavior _inspector = new MyEndpointBehavior()
_clientBase.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(_inspector);
```

Then, when I make a call, I use this code that is located in the new abstract base class (the original code did it this way, and so far the only difference is the use of generics):

```
ClientBase<TInterface> _clientBase = _client as ClientBase<TInterface>;
using (new OperationContextScope(_clientBase.InnerChannel))
{
  // Get the method
  MethodInfo mi = _client.GetType().GetMethod(APICall);

  // Make the call and return the result if successful
  object response = mi.Invoke(_client, APICallParameters);
  return response;
}
```

Any ideas why this worked prior to the switchover to generic methods and not now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this made a difference, but I re-ordered the code to move the inspector addition to happen immediately after the client creation, so the code now looks like this:

```
...sanity checks, etc...
TClient client = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClient), binding, new 
EndpointAddress(url)) as TClient;
ClientBase<TInterface> _clientBase = client as ClientBase<TInterface>;
MyEndpointBehavior _inspector = new MyEndpointBehavior()
_clientBase.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(_inspector);
...credentials, timeout, etc...
```

The inspector now seems to work as expected. Strange.